# ow to create a regex pattern for branch on github?

Tags: github

I want to do the following, I have the following branches:

1. master
2. hml
3. dsv
4. TESTING

I have other branches that are created dynamically because of the values, such as:

1. STORY_XYZ
2. BUG_XYZ
3. release_vx.y.z

What I want to do is this,

For branches other than (master, hml, dsv and TESTING) I need to apply the other github rules.

The pattern I tried was this one, but it didn't work, it is giving an error in the pattern:

```
^(?!master$|hml$|dsv$|TESTING$).*$
```

Comment: Consider putting your story, bug, and release branches in subdirectories to better organize and reference them. `story/xyz`, `bug/xyz`, `release/vx.y.z`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Branches are just files and directories.

Github branch protection rules do not use regular expressions; they use Ruby's [`File.fnmatch`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/File.html#method-c-fnmatch) which is similar to a shell glob. It does not use the `File::FNM_EXTGLOB`, so regular expressions are not available.

AFAIK there is no way to say "every branch except these branches".

However, you can restructure your branches to take advantage of subdirectories.

- `story/XYZ`
- `bug/XYZ`
- `release/vx.y.z`

Now you can write a rule which only matches branches in a subdirectory: `*/*`.

This is a bit fragile. You can consider restructuring your branches (for example, can stories and bugs be simply issues?). Depends on what your rule is.